# I need a query for the following data

Tags: mysql

```
date            name    batch
------------------------------
2016-01-01      Ram     batch1

2016-01-01      Hari    batch1

2016-01-01      Venkat  batch2

2016-01-01      Ravi    batch2

2016-01-02      Ram     batch1

2016-01-02      Hari    batch1

2016-01-02      Venkat  batch2

2016-01-02      Ravi    batch2
```

I need output like:

```
date            count   batch
-----------------------------
2016-01-01      2       batch1
2016-01-01      2       batch2
2016-01-02      2       batch1
2016-01-02      2       batch2
```

Comment: It's a simple `GROUP BY` operation on two fields. Check the referred post for more details.

Comment: thanks i got the solution

Comment: Just do a `SELECT date, batch, COUNT(name) FROM mytable GROUP BY date, batch`.

Comment: Thanks, Giorgos Betsos